# GitHub: Bring a file into a separate repo

Tags: git, repository, github, clone, cherry-pick

I need a specific file from an online repo brought into the local clone of my current project. I'd also like the file in a specific directory in the current project. I don't want to go the easiest route (copy the file from the clone); I'd rather have the file be updatable from the online repo and have that file pushed to my current project's online repo.

Thanks,
DZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might be able to use submodules:

http://speirs.org/blog/2009/5/11/understanding-git-submodules.html

they heard you like git, so they put git inside your git, so you can git while you git.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like [git-submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)